# IONIC: File size getting increasing after copying file from internal storage to application directory using file plugin

Tags: android, ios, cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugin-file

I have copied an image from my laptop to android mobile's internal storage. Then I've opened my Ionic app, selected that Image, and copied it to the application directory using the file plugin.

On my mac laptop, the image size was 8.1 MB, after copying it into the mobile device it became 7.74 MB. Then after copying it to the application directory using my app it became 10.60 MB.

- Laptop to Mobile: 8.1 MB to 7.74 MB
- Mobile storage to application directory: 7.74 MB to 10.6 MB

Code I've used:

```
let copiedFile = await this.file.copyFile(fileParent, fileName, window.localStorage.getItem(STORAGE.PERSISTENT_STORAGE_PATH), fileName);
```

Here I've used the Ionic native file plugin for copying files.

Is there any specific reason behind happening this??

Please help me if anyone knows the reason or solution for this.

Comment: That should not happen. Not a single byte should be added or removed during a copy. You are doing it wrong. At least you could show the code your app used.

Comment: Are you using `base64` by any chance?

Comment: @NajamUsSaqib I'm not using base64.

Comment: Share your Code.

Comment: Added a line of code that I've used to copy the file.

Comment: Very generous. And now we know exactly what you do you think.

Comment: I'm using the Telerik-image-picker plugin and it's re-writing the by correcting image rotation. Does it affect the size of an image?